# Mediawiki - read text from a string

Tags: mediawiki

I have a managed wiki based on Mediawiki.

The name of a typical page is `Lab book 2018/01`, and I want to extract the year  (`2018`) and the month (`02`).

I can use `#titleparts`, but the issue is that it uses `/` as delimiters, so it returns either `Lab book 2018`, or `02`.

How would I extract the year? i.e. just text from a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ParserFunctions extension installed, you can explode by any character https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions##explode:

Comment: I don't seem to have that particular extension installed.

Comment: According to your other comments in other threads you do have it, it is part of Extension:ParserFunctions https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions .

You just need to enable them in LocalSettings.php via ```$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;```

Comment: where do I find that file?

Comment: It is in the root folder of your MediaWiki install, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php

Comment: THanks I installed it.